# Error installing Cassandra 3.11.12, returns "Processing Conflict: cassandra22-2.2.7.1 conflicts cassandra"

Tags: cassandra

I have a problem with up upgrade the Cassandra version from 2.2.x to 3.11.x.

I don't understand why it's the same Cassandra 2.2.x, but when installing with package  [cassandra-2.2.19-1.noarch.rpm](https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/redhat/22x/cassandra-2.2.19-1.noarch.rpm) , it can upgrade normally, while installing with package [cassandra22-2.2.8-1.noarch.rpm](https://rpm.datastax.com/community/noarch/cassandra22-2.2.8-1.noarch.rpm), it gives an error as figure below.
[image]

Unfortunately, my server is installing the rpm package cassandra22-2.2.8-1.noarch.rpm. Please help me upgrade this Cassandra version.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cassandra22-2.2.7-1.noarch` is not a valid package so my guess is that you downloaded it from a non-official source.

You will need to uninstall it first before you can install a newer version of Cassandra. Then, you need to add the official repo to `/etc/yum.repos.d/cassandra/repo`. For Cassandra 3.11, the correct repo is:

```
[cassandra]
name=Apache Cassandra
baseurl=https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/redhat/311x/
```

You should then be able to install the latest version of Cassandra 3.11. For more info, see [Installing Cassandra 3.11](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html#installing-the-rpm-packages). Cheers!